# how to show Chinese characters in python?

Tags: python, character, cjk

PYTHON: trying to catch content from a Chinese website, but the return shows no Chinese characters.  How to solve this problem?

#### code:

```
import urllib.request
doc="http://data.eastmoney.com/cjsj/weeklystockaccountsnew.aspx?p=1"
st = urllib.request.urlopen(doc)
ct = st.read()
print(ct)
st.close()
```

Comment: The website shows how many new A-share accounts are opened for the past week, updated weekly.

Comment: Can you give some additional clarification on what exactly you want to scrape?

Comment: Just try chinese character works, not about info la.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The byte object that you read is in the Chinese GB2312 encoding. You have to decode it to a Unicode string before using:

```
ct = st.read().decode('gb2312')
```

Comment: Many many thanks man.  Both 'gb2312' and 'gbk' works.  Appreciate your help. Cheers!